# How to access(Remote Control) iOS device virtually to test the applications from browser or some other tool?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

I have an iPhone with me, I want to share the same device virtually to some of my friends who resides in different locations. So that they can access that device virtually (either using browser or any other tool) and install apps, play with those apps. Can we implement this feature. If YES, how can we implement such feature, what are the available frameworks available.

What is the procedure to implement this feature.

Many Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont get it, you want that other person can be able to remotly control your device? or as Steve Rosenberg's answer, to send an app for beta testing :O?

Comment: Yes, I want my friends to operate my device remotely. They should be able to access spring board(home), all apps installed in the device, install apps from App Store, play with the apps installed on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to share your device's screen through the internet like your suggesting.

But if your ultimate goal is beta test your app and they have devices too you can use [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) a built-in feature in iTunes connect that allows you to distribute your app to others through there email.

Comment: My requirement is sharing the device virtually with multiple peoples not distributing the apps.  They should be able to access spring board(home), all apps installed in the device, install apps from App Store, play with the apps installed on the device.

Comment: I doubt that is currently possible without being jailbroken.